# VBS Remove file/folder from random named generated folder

Tags: variables, vbscript, path, directory

I need delete 1 folder and 1 file from FF Appdata directory.
Now I have this

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
UserProfile = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
AppData = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local")
If objFSO.FolderExists(AppData &"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%FOLDERNAME%\cache2\") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFolder AppData &"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%FOLDERNAME%\cache2\"
End If

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
UserProfile = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
AppData = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%")
If objFSO.FileExists(AppData &"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%FOLDER%\sessionCheckpoints.json") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile AppData &"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%FOLDER%\sessionCheckpoints.json"
End If
```

I need replace \%FOLDER\ to correctly precising directory for this M$ **** language.
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you really want to do here, there are two possible approaches:

1. If you want, as the title suggests, to just get the name of a folder you cannot know because it was randomly generated you can query all subfolders like this:

   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   Set subFolders = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles").SubFolders
   For Each folder in subFolders
       Wscript.Echo folder.Path
   Next

Then in the loop do your work for each folder.
Additional advantage of this is that it will also work if there is more than one folder.

2. It might be that what you really want is to not do this work in any folder that is present but the correct one. In this case you would have to figure out what the correct name for the active Firefox profile is. Best way for this is to user the same method Firefox itself uses to determine this which is profiles.ini. It is located in %AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox.
   You can read it with

   Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

   Set File = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles.ini", ForReading, False)

   Do While Not File.AtEndOfStream
       strWS = File.ReadLine()
   Loop

The format is described [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profiles.ini_file). Now normally you could just check for the line like "Path=Profiles/qioxtndq.default", if users use multiple profiles and switch it might be more complicated but that depends a lot on your workplace.